# TypeError: _realm.default.open is not a function

Tags: react-native, realm

[image]

I'm using realm 10.14.0 with react native 0.68.0,

if if i downgrade realm version I'm having same error

Comment: It’s a good idea to include code, errors and and structures as *text*, not links and images. That way, if they are needed in an answer, they can be copied and pasted. See [images and links are evil](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Lastly, images are not searchable which may prevent future readers from locating the question. Also, take a look at [No Images Please](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). It doesn't appear like Realm is available - have you ensured Realm is properly configured?

Answer (score 1):

I was faced same issue but after updating the react-native version to 0.69.1 & realm version to 10.19.5 it works for me.